# Re-format daily data into weekly data in pandas while keeping multiple rows that correspond to weekly date

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily data that has 2 datapoints for each date. So for 10/13/2015 there's 2 datapoints, and for 10/14/2015 there's 2 datapoints. I need to keep the 2 datapoints from 10/13/2015, then skip a week to 10/20/2015 and show the 2 datapoints from that week.

I tried the resample function to convert daily into weekly data but it did not work

Here is my df:

[image]

Here is the code I tried.I expected the code to keep both rows both from 10/13/15 and then provide both row values from 10/20/15.

```
PortfolioReturns.set_index('Date').resample('W', how='first')
```

That produces:

[image]

But I need the first 2 rows of 10/13/2015, then move a week forward to 10/20/15 and provide the corresponding data, then move a week forward and provide the 2 rows of data for 10/27/15, and so on. Final result should look like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that Date is converted to `datetime` and second that both `Date` and `FX` are part of multiindex:

```
PortfolioReturns.Date =  pd.to_datetime(PortfolioReturns.Date)

PortfolioReturns = PortfolioReturns.set_index(['Date', 'FX'])
```

Then use next line to get wanted result:

```
PortfolioReturns.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq='W'), pd.Grouper(level='FX')]).sum()
```

Comment: resetting the index by 'Date' and 'FX' works as it only 2 currencies are shown for each date. But when I use your next line of code the output has 3 currencies for each date rather than the expected 2. I'm not sure why that is. Does another grouper function needed to be added?

Comment: Can  you show me example of the data frame and `3 currencies` in the output?

Comment: I had to post an answer to provide more details. Let me know what you think, thanks.

Comment: can you please share the original data as well. And please don't share image of the data frame cause I can't do nothing with that.  Maybe something like this:  `print("PortfolioReturns = pd.DataFrame( %s )" % (str(PortfolioReturns.to_dict())))
` so you can post data frame so I can recreate it on my side

Comment: @miloas.ai please see updated answer for original data and results. thanks

Comment: @HDBrew ok so you need to set Date to datetime first and then set multiindex. please check my updated answer

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that mistake easily. But I'm still running into the problem where after the final sort/group the final df shows 3-5 currencies in some instances where it should only show 2. Please see updated answer for details.

Comment: why it should show only 2 currencies? which ones? You have 5 different currencies `'EUR', 'AUD', 'NZD', 'GBP', 'NOK'` in your example

Comment: The original df has 2 currencies per date. Those 2 currencies came from a previous sort that narrowed them down into the "final" currencies. So the original df has 2 currencies per date, but when I apply the suggested code somehow more are shown. So for 10/6/2015 EUR and AUD should show. Skip a week forward to 10/13/15 and NZD and AUD show show. Skip a week forward to 10/20/15 and GBP and NZD should show. All I'm trying to do is instead of showing daily data, show weekly data.

Comment: sample data that you have provided have more then 2 currencies. Maybe you should add more info , create small simple example that can be scaled to your problem, cause I have to admit I am loosing you , I am not sure what is your issue with data and code anymore.

Comment: The sample data in the df has 2 currencies for each date? Nevermind though. I appreciate your help as I'll be able to use your suggestion in other areas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the first 100 rows of the original df I am trying to sort:

```
df = {'Date': {2: ('2015-10-06 00:00:00'), 0: ('2015-10-06 00:00:00'), 14: ('2015-10-07 00:00:00'), 8: ('2015-10-07 00:00:00'), 22: ('2015-10-08 00:00:00'), 16: ('2015-10-08 00:00:00'), 30: ('2015-10-09 00:00:00'), 24: ('2015-10-09 00:00:00'), 38: ('2015-10-12 00:00:00'), 32: ('2015-10-12 00:00:00'), 46: ('2015-10-13 00:00:00'), 40: ('2015-10-13 00:00:00'), 54: ('2015-10-14 00:00:00'), 48: ('2015-10-14 00:00:00'), 62: ('2015-10-15 00:00:00'), 56: ('2015-10-15 00:00:00'), 70: ('2015-10-16 00:00:00'), 67: ('2015-10-16 00:00:00'), 78: ('2015-10-19 00:00:00'), 75: ('2015-10-19 00:00:00'), 83: ('2015-10-20 00:00:00'), 86: ('2015-10-20 00:00:00'), 91: ('2015-10-21 00:00:00'), 88: ('2015-10-21 00:00:00'), 99: ('2015-10-22 00:00:00'), 96: ('2015-10-22 00:00:00'), 107: ('2015-10-23 00:00:00'), 104: ('2015-10-23 00:00:00'), 115: ('2015-10-26 00:00:00'), 112: ('2015-10-26 00:00:00'), 120: ('2015-10-27 00:00:00'), 123: ('2015-10-27 00:00:00'), 131: ('2015-10-28 00:00:00'), 133: ('2015-10-28 00:00:00'), 139: ('2015-10-29 00:00:00'), 141: ('2015-10-29 00:00:00'), 147: ('2015-10-30 00:00:00'), 149: ('2015-10-30 00:00:00'), 155: ('2015-11-02 00:00:00'), 152: ('2015-11-02 00:00:00'), 163: ('2015-11-03 00:00:00'), 160: ('2015-11-03 00:00:00'), 171: ('2015-11-04 00:00:00'), 168: ('2015-11-04 00:00:00'), 179: ('2015-11-05 00:00:00'), 176: ('2015-11-05 00:00:00'), 187: ('2015-11-06 00:00:00'), 184: ('2015-11-06 00:00:00'), 195: ('2015-11-09 00:00:00'), 192: ('2015-11-09 00:00:00'), 203: ('2015-11-10 00:00:00'), 200: ('2015-11-10 00:00:00'), 211: ('2015-11-11 00:00:00'), 208: ('2015-11-11 00:00:00'), 219: ('2015-11-12 00:00:00'), 216: ('2015-11-12 00:00:00'), 227: ('2015-11-13 00:00:00'), 224: ('2015-11-13 00:00:00'), 235: ('2015-11-16 00:00:00'), 232: ('2015-11-16 00:00:00'), 243: ('2015-11-17 00:00:00'), 240: ('2015-11-17 00:00:00'), 251: ('2015-11-18 00:00:00'), 248: ('2015-11-18 00:00:00'), 259: ('2015-11-19 00:00:00'), 256: ('2015-11-19 00:00:00'), 267: ('2015-11-20 00:00:00'), 264: ('2015-11-20 00:00:00'), 275: ('2015-11-23 00:00:00'), 272: ('2015-11-23 00:00:00'), 283: ('2015-11-24 00:00:00'), 280: ('2015-11-24 00:00:00'), 291: ('2015-11-25 00:00:00'), 288: ('2015-11-25 00:00:00'), 299: ('2015-11-26 00:00:00'), 296: ('2015-11-26 00:00:00'), 307: ('2015-11-27 00:00:00'), 304: ('2015-11-27 00:00:00'), 315: ('2015-11-30 00:00:00'), 312: ('2015-11-30 00:00:00'), 323: ('2015-12-01 00:00:00'), 320: ('2015-12-01 00:00:00'), 331: ('2015-12-02 00:00:00'), 328: ('2015-12-02 00:00:00'), 339: ('2015-12-03 00:00:00'), 336: ('2015-12-03 00:00:00'), 347: ('2015-12-04 00:00:00'), 344: ('2015-12-04 00:00:00'), 355: ('2015-12-07 00:00:00'), 352: ('2015-12-07 00:00:00'), 363: ('2015-12-08 00:00:00'), 360: ('2015-12-08 00:00:00'), 371: ('2015-12-09 00:00:00'), 368: ('2015-12-09 00:00:00'), 379: ('2015-12-10 00:00:00'), 376: ('2015-12-10 00:00:00'), 387: ('2015-12-11 00:00:00'), 384: ('2015-12-11 00:00:00'), 395: ('2015-12-14 00:00:00'), 392: ('2015-12-14 00:00:00')}, 'FX': {2: 'EUR', 0: 'AUD', 14: 'NZD', 8: 'AUD', 22: 'NZD', 16: 'AUD', 30: 'NZD', 24: 'AUD', 38: 'NZD', 32: 'AUD', 46: 'NZD', 40: 'AUD', 54: 'NZD', 48: 'AUD', 62: 'NZD', 56: 'AUD', 70: 'NZD', 67: 'GBP', 78: 'NZD', 75: 'GBP', 83: 'GBP', 86: 'NZD', 91: 'GBP', 88: 'AUD', 99: 'GBP', 96: 'AUD', 107: 'GBP', 104: 'AUD', 115: 'GBP', 112: 'AUD', 120: 'AUD', 123: 'GBP', 131: 'GBP', 133: 'NOK', 139: 'GBP', 141: 'NOK', 147: 'GBP', 149: 'NOK', 155: 'GBP', 152: 'AUD', 163: 'GBP', 160: 'AUD', 171: 'GBP', 168: 'AUD', 179: 'GBP', 176: 'AUD', 187: 'GBP', 184: 'AUD', 195: 'GBP', 192: 'AUD', 203: 'GBP', 200: 'AUD', 211: 'GBP', 208: 'AUD', 219: 'GBP', 216: 'AUD', 227: 'GBP', 224: 'AUD', 235: 'GBP', 232: 'AUD', 243: 'GBP', 240: 'AUD', 251: 'GBP', 248: 'AUD', 259: 'GBP', 256: 'AUD', 267: 'GBP', 264: 'AUD', 275: 'GBP', 272: 'AUD', 283: 'GBP', 280: 'AUD', 291: 'GBP', 288: 'AUD', 299: 'GBP', 296: 'AUD', 307: 'GBP', 304: 'AUD', 315: 'GBP', 312: 'AUD', 323: 'GBP', 320: 'AUD', 331: 'GBP', 328: 'AUD', 339: 'GBP', 336: 'AUD', 347: 'GBP', 344: 'AUD', 355: 'GBP', 352: 'AUD', 363: 'GBP', 360: 'AUD', 371: 'GBP', 368: 'AUD', 379: 'GBP', 376: 'AUD', 387: 'GBP', 384: 'AUD', 395: 'GBP', 392: 'AUD'}, 'PR': {2: 2.5940924021958356, 0: -2.345027933813937, 14: 2.926937202968438, 8: -1.6307734656660244, 22: 2.459777675682151, 16: -0.5595659171734435, 30: 2.3267953090161386, 24: -0.28308617341508135, 38: 3.9328663027589528, 32: 0.9264073816576346, 46: 5.279066565178647, 40: 0.9771661398017883, 54: 6.239094843157922, 48: -0.1271017881572245, 62: 6.7802581850678445, 56: -0.2076963240833507, 70: 8.27158026828474, 67: 2.9395197799839012, 78: 8.309292096695998, 75: 0.6662134386850704, 83: 1.2455581316308972, 86: 8.42085024815713, 91: -0.37521597280743, 88: -1.2803936868845178, 99: -0.36642170841582056, 96: -2.1072491247172365, 107: 0.3883691766043862, 104: -0.42654375595161387, 115: 0.44281101251737454, 112: -1.0073195063536655, 120: -1.8810745928043104, 123: 0.028443645438169796, 131: 0.5565300515294025, 133: 5.153899866009937, 139: -0.8997702153901388, 141: 2.590325470289634, 147: -1.5851969892705986, 149: 3.488503580851865, 155: -2.820909589442866, 152: -6.26633669890686, 163: -1.6085154524450695, 160: -4.6060040453178575, 171: -0.63666239539385, 168: -4.77153099524954, 179: -2.664570570441993, 176: -5.599350140918924, 187: -3.01199026125184, 184: -4.982723764013963, 195: -4.142988530950598, 192: -7.413959443168827, 203: -5.08179239931934, 200: -7.394925970153632, 211: -4.982346018046291, 208: -6.849792397188925, 219: -6.539969505554344, 216: -5.88643774964307, 227: -7.794045618609136, 224: -6.8927958722033384, 235: -7.6339307853335425, 232: -7.938769037298366, 243: -6.043342521024531, 240: -5.175220087941746, 251: -6.411561558652168, 248: -4.675778594025992, 259: -5.475465161425197, 256: -2.1479412423930366, 267: -5.154591324918767, 264: -0.9301591407010701, 275: -6.595849948746513, 272: -0.3394456420020675, 283: -6.724726923128365, 280: -2.329392242273398, 291: -5.845963685200428, 288: -2.4306707278933803, 299: -4.993780808034276, 296: -3.228115676956067, 307: -5.179953059603603, 304: -3.4401839858864136, 315: -5.452189771249893, 312: -2.518821681816008, 323: -3.9168495741673026, 320: 1.3601372180706672, 331: -4.763649308079088, 328: -0.17148221949723208, 339: -6.575172370668025, 336: -1.491172366064475, 347: -6.60361680817203, 344: -3.743895106094619, 355: -7.7017992418624726, 352: -3.064636345877736, 363: -8.047331070194751, 360: -4.593745408515016, 371: -6.168800836821364, 368: -3.4992940491311075, 379: -6.338268687577308, 376: -3.896363765798738, 387: -7.87594595849389, 384: -3.527579769999334, 395: -6.770275353417032, 392: -5.2277102570913}, 'ZS': {2: -3.76394848722557, 0: -1.6557236828634454, 14: -5.639411628859669, 8: -2.9588026374975156, 22: -6.020160738494453, 16: -3.2403165975010055, 30: -6.101629985627668, 24: -4.378902459821516, 38: -5.838804072807298, 32: -4.386332739139463, 46: -4.776203149489422, 40: -3.3429694730986683, 54: -4.971489031279462, 48: -2.6451681270971603, 62: -4.044415778990285, 56: -2.4286498374534187, 70: -3.1893771017305887, 67: -2.212007395580608, 78: -2.2433841617648427, 75: -1.9922763865584925, 83: -2.442558136350233, 86: -1.7034640320878454, 91: -1.5396511553476144, 88: -1.0511251323947246, 99: -2.0887727362916197, 96: -1.3495135923499597, 107: -1.981051825531738, 104: -1.4546676129564606, 115: -1.8167116072510832, 112: -1.8003509084051594, 120: -1.0086112702561665, 123: -0.7750216049007349, 131: -0.93149415696279, 133: -0.2463709869323678, 139: -3.126029798243559, 141: -0.9624212387156673, 147: -3.708070437013109, 149: -0.7466532865880979, 155: -3.1631255147633794, 152: -0.8744163039723445, 163: -3.754219340880911, 160: -1.1732483946433625, 171: -4.238779918767839, 168: -1.4636819615115961, 179: -3.4087298137444506, 176: -2.4287724234135832, 187: -3.600890796268083, 184: -1.5637704049661916, 195: -5.236195352645735, 192: -2.3436965783070285, 203: -4.802732228965693, 200: -1.9448617835155426, 211: -4.901897329840157, 208: -1.7785161448922566, 219: -4.296737975797265, 216: -2.691015153222037, 227: -3.9115918922973414, 224: -2.3303491918472123, 235: -2.774634060586057, 232: -1.6336250032533424, 243: -3.60970801763719, 240: -1.0898210084174917, 251: -3.720904287456087, 248: -0.8963745805600776, 259: -3.144533738686653, 256: -2.0925108392538263, 267: -2.690121276532827, 264: -1.7011490908409255, 275: -2.731857589534655, 272: -1.3116472799620569, 283: -3.1693473529460907, 280: -2.041832346190046, 291: -3.0320699167778384, 288: -1.4476436572572968, 299: -2.9156584058767345, 296: -1.0839136843889725, 307: -2.445950299317996, 304: -0.573909146168351, 315: -2.651849853605895, 312: -0.9769959145921803, 323: -2.1536803804059295, 320: -1.2260375546514226, 331: -1.2314010728500302, 328: -0.7357305910285333, 339: -2.965591813021671, 336: -1.525739452737485, 347: -3.0711427898943477, 344: -2.489604087555052, 355: -2.1686724190283293, 352: -1.5356236528443206, 363: -1.9812806348730883, 360: 0.042848808591871484, 371: -3.941108719604978, 368: -0.03716485114206543, 379: -3.8571485914443544, 376: -0.9755936468243593, 387: -2.5542552273508448, 384: 0.22433436422742525, 395: -2.2259619368415158, 392: 0.8799640933964463}}
```

I changed your second line of code to `.first()` instead of `.sum()` because I just need the values in the final result, not the sum.

```
PortfolioReturns.groupby([pd.Grouper(level='Date', freq='W'), pd.Grouper(level='FX')]).first()
```

When I apply the above code I would expect 2 currencies per date, but I still get 3-5 currencies in some instance for each date. Here is the final df after applying the code:

```
Final = {'PR': {(('2015-10-11 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -2.345027933813937, (('2015-10-11 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): 2.5940924021958356, (('2015-10-11 00:00:00'), 'NZD'): 2.926937202968438, (('2015-10-18 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): 0.9264073816576346, (('2015-10-18 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): 2.9395197799839012, (('2015-10-18 00:00:00'), 'NZD'): 3.9328663027589528, (('2015-10-25 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.2803936868845178, (('2015-10-25 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): 0.6662134386850704, (('2015-10-25 00:00:00'), 'NZD'): 8.309292096695998, (('2015-11-01 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.0073195063536655, (('2015-11-01 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): 0.44281101251737454, (('2015-11-01 00:00:00'), 'NOK'): 5.153899866009937, (('2015-11-08 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -6.26633669890686, (('2015-11-08 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.820909589442866, (('2015-11-15 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -7.413959443168827, (('2015-11-15 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -4.142988530950598, (('2015-11-22 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -7.938769037298366, (('2015-11-22 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -7.6339307853335425, (('2015-11-29 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -0.3394456420020675, (('2015-11-29 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -6.595849948746513, (('2015-12-06 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -2.518821681816008, (('2015-12-06 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -5.452189771249893, (('2015-12-13 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -3.064636345877736, (('2015-12-13 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -7.7017992418624726, (('2015-12-20 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -5.2277102570913, (('2015-12-20 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): -5.731937068866133, (('2015-12-20 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -6.770275353417032, (('2015-12-27 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -5.654461361645624, (('2015-12-27 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): -9.910521375756321, (('2015-12-27 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -7.798455984245112, (('2016-01-03 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -3.1589412669530414, (('2016-01-03 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -5.375094743817255, (('2016-01-10 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -2.7748056873096116, (('2016-01-10 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): -12.858172908645438, (('2016-01-10 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -6.939277314517856, (('2016-01-17 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): -14.359968633819308, (('2016-01-17 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -9.679994585565, (('2016-01-24 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): -16.14155458515284, (('2016-01-24 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -11.760583914861533, (('2016-01-24 00:00:00'), 'NOK'): -11.415386368384084, (('2016-01-31 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -9.81418719390862, (('2016-01-31 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): -17.83698200529794, (('2016-01-31 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -11.171901542931451, (('2016-01-31 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -13.988786491102513, (('2016-02-07 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -9.85934404315756, (('2016-02-07 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -10.212759652709858, (('2016-02-14 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -17.363807542698385, (('2016-02-14 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): -18.69702374229407, (('2016-02-14 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -18.038879864397195, (('2016-02-14 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -16.98533874959145, (('2016-02-21 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -17.320038575463247, (('2016-02-21 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -17.80142070257775, (('2016-02-28 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -14.697741468793591, (('2016-02-28 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -15.946575448427613, (('2016-03-06 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -17.37926256350223, (('2016-03-06 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -18.15087524312309, (('2016-03-13 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -12.5100335480684, (('2016-03-13 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -16.48957049109635, (('2016-03-20 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -10.522872632875613, (('2016-03-20 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -15.432100453748554, (('2016-03-27 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -13.209122705984965, (('2016-03-27 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -18.17732892833468, (('2016-04-03 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -13.805797334272164, (('2016-04-03 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -18.817460037020627, (('2016-04-10 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -14.967381685725456, (('2016-04-10 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -20.26743682154998, (('2016-04-17 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -16.963142696787347, (('2016-04-17 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -23.38449365430365, (('2016-04-24 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -12.27048350785881, (('2016-04-24 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -16.603475728419593, (('2016-04-24 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -10.536784397342103, (('2016-05-01 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -12.410003500920885, (('2016-05-01 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -16.05671574276514, (('2016-05-01 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -11.452614309757159, (('2016-05-01 00:00:00'), 'JPY'): -14.939505846641643, (('2016-05-08 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -16.124339319447177, (('2016-05-08 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -10.650806261138424, (('2016-05-15 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -19.00681740960356, (('2016-05-15 00:00:00'), 'JPY'): -17.7041870307855, (('2016-05-22 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -17.399043399653525, (('2016-05-22 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -11.49540743334284, (('2016-05-22 00:00:00'), 'JPY'): -17.762318696293335, (('2016-05-29 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -20.282185510744355, (('2016-05-29 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -12.732162259020551, (('2016-06-05 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -13.464005063319496, (('2016-06-05 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -10.217583968913713, (('2016-06-12 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -14.47602713382583, (('2016-06-12 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -7.806483849160872, (('2016-06-19 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -18.535330609774547, (('2016-06-19 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -10.905802868714732, (('2016-06-19 00:00:00'), 'SEK'): -17.57913524473085, (('2016-06-26 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -14.842294114242726, (('2016-06-26 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -7.547183869934204, (('2016-06-26 00:00:00'), 'SEK'): -15.014024531531934, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -5.443735047736153, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -17.291709254446175, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'JPY'): -23.868712608698317, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'NOK'): -11.799951928029396, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'SEK'): -22.518568261873906, (('2016-07-10 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -4.2217476224376105}, 'ZS': {(('2015-10-11 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.6557236828634454, (('2015-10-11 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -3.76394848722557, (('2015-10-11 00:00:00'), 'NZD'): -5.639411628859669, (('2015-10-18 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -4.386332739139463, (('2015-10-18 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.212007395580608, (('2015-10-18 00:00:00'), 'NZD'): -5.838804072807298, (('2015-10-25 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.0511251323947246, (('2015-10-25 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -1.9922763865584925, (('2015-10-25 00:00:00'), 'NZD'): -2.2433841617648427, (('2015-11-01 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.8003509084051594, (('2015-11-01 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -1.8167116072510832, (('2015-11-01 00:00:00'), 'NOK'): -0.2463709869323678, (('2015-11-08 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -0.8744163039723445, (('2015-11-08 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -3.1631255147633794, (('2015-11-15 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -2.3436965783070285, (('2015-11-15 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -5.236195352645735, (('2015-11-22 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.6336250032533424, (('2015-11-22 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.774634060586057, (('2015-11-29 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.3116472799620569, (('2015-11-29 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.731857589534655, (('2015-12-06 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -0.9769959145921803, (('2015-12-06 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.651849853605895, (('2015-12-13 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.5356236528443206, (('2015-12-13 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.1686724190283293, (('2015-12-20 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): 0.8799640933964463, (('2015-12-20 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): 0.5923420998291122, (('2015-12-20 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.2259619368415158, (('2015-12-27 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): 0.2626952476610146, (('2015-12-27 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): 0.36949976538108986, (('2015-12-27 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.3359426131707592, (('2016-01-03 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -0.5349648393829427, (('2016-01-03 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -3.123607006260713, (('2016-01-10 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -0.06655548079733803, (('2016-01-10 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): 1.5269303313085163, (('2016-01-10 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -0.9113214711215346, (('2016-01-17 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): 1.1853905788634316, (('2016-01-17 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): 0.7970662332116858, (('2016-01-24 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): 1.4892863468407243, (('2016-01-24 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): 0.7858874764474859, (('2016-01-24 00:00:00'), 'NOK'): 1.3050401969855727, (('2016-01-31 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.43396047263051, (('2016-01-31 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): 0.9336513457906168, (('2016-01-31 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.1378736854356188, (('2016-01-31 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -1.2208307271568672, (('2016-02-07 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -0.812340651737314, (('2016-02-07 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.024096884983761, (('2016-02-14 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -0.44514741317094086, (('2016-02-14 00:00:00'), 'CAD'): 2.29674236518028, (('2016-02-14 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -2.3929920247345233, (('2016-02-14 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -1.227436227850491, (('2016-02-21 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -2.245831598633664, (('2016-02-21 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.5996498473796799, (('2016-02-28 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -3.542298018506571, (('2016-02-28 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -0.29072980340482657, (('2016-03-06 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -2.2833990559048654, (('2016-03-06 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): 0.28631817186922937, (('2016-03-13 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -5.93710891177702, (('2016-03-13 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -2.9804902863240588, (('2016-03-20 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -4.680452038636961, (('2016-03-20 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -2.686140459482902, (('2016-03-27 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.7412763785656047, (('2016-03-27 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -2.1069923087441116, (('2016-04-03 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -2.1745656281406602, (('2016-04-03 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.3859410179807528, (('2016-04-10 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -2.0036569331054848, (('2016-04-10 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.808395193317656, (('2016-04-17 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.862760349113428, (('2016-04-17 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.7547482749243373, (('2016-04-24 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -4.264745981493886, (('2016-04-24 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.70117867086471, (('2016-04-24 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -3.7898637554210177, (('2016-05-01 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -3.9632133964910006, (('2016-05-01 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -2.350242229820067, (('2016-05-01 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -4.572946952782972, (('2016-05-01 00:00:00'), 'JPY'): -3.1554178849249457, (('2016-05-08 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -3.318737989604724, (('2016-05-08 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.8613850117910222, (('2016-05-15 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -0.3565309390145314, (('2016-05-15 00:00:00'), 'JPY'): 0.3555339715838687, (('2016-05-22 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.183156055956193, (('2016-05-22 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -0.8993497968028573, (('2016-05-22 00:00:00'), 'JPY'): -0.7922871149594519, (('2016-05-29 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.5641195185720203, (('2016-05-29 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.4971754868721714, (('2016-06-05 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -1.4499652586765128, (('2016-06-05 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -2.462555676477037, (('2016-06-12 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -2.5584407690112485, (('2016-06-12 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): 0.14659196141606035, (('2016-06-19 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -2.4702353660227616, (('2016-06-19 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): 0.38174761159519055, (('2016-06-19 00:00:00'), 'SEK'): 0.2618517565012646, (('2016-06-26 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): -3.1679088765510306, (('2016-06-26 00:00:00'), 'GBP'): -3.8501654690363223, (('2016-06-26 00:00:00'), 'SEK'): -2.6331602504054237, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -1.0208074465662567, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'EUR'): 0.9414605191324238, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'JPY'): 2.425733331724266, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'NOK'): -0.31776553918522277, (('2016-07-03 00:00:00'), 'SEK'): -0.47549933187726223, (('2016-07-10 00:00:00'), 'AUD'): -3.1581389009783516}}
```